# Quarto: Running different R code in dependency of the output format

Tags: r, quarto

I have a qmd Quarto file with different output formats, html and pdf.

My goal is, to generate graphics in dependence of the output format.

How can I detect in an R cell, if the processing output format is html or pdf?
A simple if statement would be sufficient.

```
---
title: My title 
format:
  html:
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 3
    html-math-method: katex
  pdf:
    keep-tex: true
    toc: true
    number-sections: true
    colorlinks: true
---
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `knitr::is_html_output` you could do:

````
---
title: My title 
format:
   html:
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 3
    html-math-method: katex
  pdf:
    keep-tex: true
    toc: true
    number-sections: true
    colorlinks: true
---

```{r}
if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
  print("HTML")
} else {
  print("pdf")
}
```
````

Which in case of `html` will give:

[image]

and for `pdf`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also make use of pandoc divs with the `.content-visible` or `.content-hidden` classes along with `when-format` clause which supports a variety of format and format aliases such as, `pdf`, `latex`, `html`, `html:js` etc.

[See here](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/conditional.html) for details.

````
---
title: My title
format:
  html:
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 3
    html-math-method: katex
  pdf:
    keep-tex: true
    toc: true
    number-sections: true
    colorlinks: true
---


::: {.content-visible when-format="html"}

```{r}
print("Output for html document")
```

:::



::: {.content-visible when-format="pdf"}

```{r}
print("Output for pdf document")
```

:::
````

**html output**

---

[image: HTML output]

---

**pdf output**

---

[image: PDF output]

---